# How to output commands when running lynx from bash script?

Tags: bash, scripts, lynx

I have a bash script that executes a web-based php script using lynx, then the browser stays active allowing the user to input commands. I would like to automate quitting lynx and continuing with the rest of the script.

In the script I have:

```
lynx "https://www.domain.com/script.php?"
[rest of script]
```

Is there a way to output a `q` followed by a `y` so the script will continue without needing input from the keyboard?

Comment: Post your script and explain why you are using lynx for this task and what interaction / input you need / anticipate from a user running the script

Comment: I don't necessarily need lynx though i'm running it from within a vagrant vm  so it seems to be the easiest working solution (firefox & chrome would need to be installed & configured from within the vm)  that i'm aware of. Once the web-based script is complete I want to (q)uit & confirm (y) and continue the script. This will always be the input, just trying to automate it.

Comment: Why lynx and not curl or wget?

Comment: @sudodus check which post you edited :)

Comment: @muru using curl is actually the simplest solution and avoids other users having to install lynx.  I marked the answer below as it answers this specific question. Thanks.

Comment: I removed my answer, because there were better solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-dump` argument.

Example of **lynx** in a script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

buffer=$(lynx -dump "https://www.domain.com/script.php?")

copyright=$(echo "$buffer"|egrep Copyright)
phonenumber=$(echo "$buffer"|egrep "]Call.*Chat"|awk '{print $5}')

echo -e "This domain has this Copyright notice:\n$copyright"
echo "Phone contact is: $phonenumber"
```

**Running the above tested script will give this output:**

```
$ ./script.sh
This domain has this Copyright notice:
   © Copyright  2017 Domain.com. All rights reserved.
Phone contact is: 800-403-3568
```